# window label doesn't show

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get the `NewWindow` label to show random phrases from the `anecdotes` list, but it doesn't seem to work. The `NewWindow` shows up as normal, but it doesn't have a label. Sorry if the code isn't the best, I'm fairly new to programming.

```
def on_closing():
    pass
def newWind():
    newWindow=Toplevel()
    frame=Frame(newWindow)
    def phrase_refresh():
        new_phrase = random.choice(anecdotes)
        newWindow.after(1000, phrase_refresh)
    phrase=phrase_refresh()
    label=Label(newWindow, text=phrase)
    label.pack()
    newWindow.update()
    newWindow.title('lol')
    newWindow.geometry('200x200')
```

Comment: I'm sure the Label is there, you just never give it any text to display.  Assigning to a local variable inside `phrase_refresh()` isn't going to magically change the Label, you need to explicitly do `label['text'] = whatever`.

Comment: There are a couple problems here. 1) You don't actually set the label's text when you call `phrase_refresh()`, as jasonharper mentioned. 2) `phrase = phrase_refresh()` sets `phrase` to `None`, because there's no `return` statement inside `phrase_refresh()`. That's why you can't see the label; because you set the text to `None`.